# Logstash Ruby Invalid escape character syntax

Tags: ruby, logstash

I have to parse this kinds of logs with ruby:

```
test = "LogicalDisk\C:\% Free Space=40.04815, LogicalDisk\C:\Free Megabytes=32606, LogicalDisk\E:\% Free Space=91.81561, LogicalDisk\E:\Free Megabytes=18802, LogicalDisk\F:\% Free Space=n/a, LogicalDisk\F:\Free Megabytes=n/a, LogicalDisk\HarddiskVolume1\
```

But gives me this error:

```
main.rb:2: Invalid escape character syntax
test = "LogicalDisk\C:\% Free Space=40.04815, Logic
                     ^
```

This logs are extracted with logstash from a DB, I cannot use gsub to replace the invalid characters , because error is trown at the moment ruby reads the string, and stop there.

what can I do to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--if you're rrading from a file this isn't an issue. If you're just testing, escape the test string properly.

Comment: I cant escape it is a string that comes from a DB, retrieved by logstash

Comment: If you are reading strings from a DB or file you don't need to do anything. The reason you're having a problem is because you're creating your own string and not escaping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure I fully understand your use case but if you’re doing something like manually copying and pasting directly from one location into your Ruby code then you can define your string using delimited input like this:

```
string= %q{LogicalDisk\C:\% Free Space=40.04815, LogicalDisk\C:\Free Megabytes=32606, LogicalDisk\E:\% Free Space=91.81561, LogicalDisk\E:\Free Megabytes=18802, LogicalDisk\F:\% Free Space=n/a, LogicalDisk\F:\Free Megabytes=n/a, LogicalDisk\HarddiskVolume1\ }.strip
```

What you’re doing is defining the string using the curly brackets as delimiters instead of using quotation marks.  The main problem with your example is the trailing backslash which will cancel out the closing quotation when Ruby tries to convert to a string.  To deal with this, I placed a trailing space inside the delimiters and then just stripped it off afterward using the strip method.  You could also optionally add a second trailing backslash to cancel out the first one.